# Twisted count up timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a simple little javascript count up timer on my page that I want to tweak, but really don't know where to begin.

The goal is that instead of it counting straight up in timed intervals is to have it jump randomly upward.

for example, if my timer is showing 100 and is set to increase again in 1 second, instead of it showing 101, I want it to show some random number between 101 & 106.

Any nods in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
I appreciate the help you guys gave me (posts 1&2) ... but i'm still missing it somehow.

Here is the link to what i currently have... http://jsfiddle.net/FQSAH/19/

As you see it run, it's moving up by 1, but i'm wanting it to move up by a random number between     1&5 each time.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 0;

setTimeout(function() {
  // random interval between 1 and 10
  var interval = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  x += interval;
}, 1000);
```

Tweak 10 as large as you want for a higher variability in intervals.

Comment: Very appreciated - This gets me to the goal.

Answer (score 0):

With a `setInterval()` you could schedule a function to run every second.
To get the random effect working, you could create a function to update a variable using `Math.random()`.

For example:

```
var value = 0;

function randomize() {
    value += (1 + (Math.random() * 5)); //random value between 1 and 5
}

setInterval(randomize, 1000);
```

Comment: Perfect - This made my life so much easier - Thanks for that!

Comment: The problem with your current code is that you're not using the `Math.random` method.